# Xaml Page to choose profile picture from the system

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

My question is about creating a xaml page where picture are given by the system user can choose between the picture and selected the avator.
On the Mouse click action the selected picture must be displayed above to show the user selection.
[Please check the image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7MUS.jpg)

```
 <PivotItem>
                <Grid
                    Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <!--  Security question  -->
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--  Steps  -->
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Style="{StaticResource PopUpHeading1}"
                        Text="Finally, please selesct your Healthi character" />
                    <!--  First security question stackpanel  -->
                    <Button>
                        <Image
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Height="226"
                        Margin="111,50,0,0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Source="{StaticResource ProfilePicture}" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                    </Button>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Button>
                            <Image
                                Height="67"
                                Source="{StaticResource ProfilePicture}">
                            </Image>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Background="Transparent">
                            <Image
                            Height="67"
                                    Source="{StaticResource ProfilePicture0}">
                            </Image>
                        </Button>
                        <Image
                        Height="82"
                                    Source="{StaticResource ProfilePicture1}">
                        </Image>
                        <Image
                        Height="67"
                                    Source="{StaticResource ProfilePicture2}">
                        </Image>
                        <Image
                        Height="67"
                                    Source="{StaticResource ProfilePicture3}">
                        </Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [FileOpenPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker) class to select a picture from a folder. For example, you could select a picture from the `PicturesLibrary` of the system like the examples on the above document.

Then, you would get a [StorageFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile#definition) class object of the picture. After that, you could call its [GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getscaledimageasthumbnailasync#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync_Windows_Storage_FileProperties_ThumbnailMode_) to  get a scaled image as a thumbnail. You could check the [File and folder thumbnail sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/FileThumbnails) for reference.

Finally, you could use [Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image) control to show the thumbnail.